# Find characters in string and make them a link in php

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, str-replace

I have 1000s of posts in Wordpress that have this weird code for a hyperlink in the body copy. For example, I want to find all instances of this:

```
[Website Name](http://www.website.com)
```

and turn it into

```
<a href="http://www.website.com">Website Name</a>
```

What is the best way to achieve this in php?

```
$string = "This is a blog post hey check out this website [Website Name](http://www.website.com). It is a real good domain.
// do some magic
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: It's not weird code though... It's markdown.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I'm not good at regex and finding and replacing strings in text. I assume I need some regex match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with this regex:

```
\[([^]]+)]\((http[^)]+)\)
```

It looks for a `[`, followed by some non-`]` characters, a `]` and `(http`, then some non-`)` characters until a `)`.

This is then replaced with `<a href="$2">$1</a>`. For example:

```
$string = "This is a blog post hey check out this website [Website Name](http://www.website.com). It is a real good domain.";
echo preg_replace('/\[([^]]+)]\((http[^)]+)\)/', '<a href="$2">$1</a>', $string);
```

Output:

```
This is a blog post hey check out this website <a href="http://www.website.com">Website Name</a>. It is a real good domain.
```

Answer (score 0):

This weird code is [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) (used for example here in SO).

If you want to convert it to HTML using PHP you could use this library : https://parsedown.org/

The advantage is that you will convert any other markdown tags and other forms of markdown links present in the posts.